# Responsive five column layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I want to make five column responsive design with 15px margin in between them. In normal screen it should fill five and in tablet it should be 2 in a row as in the following diagram.

I got something like [this](http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/) but it's not working with 15px margin in between them.

Anyone have a sample?

**Desktop**

```
--------------   --------------   --------------   --------------   --------------
|            |   |            |   |            |   |            |   |            |
|            |   |            |   |            |   |            |   |            |
|     1      |   |      2     |   |      3     |   |      4     |   |      5     |
|            |   |            |   |            |   |            |   |            |
|            |   |            |   |            |   |            |   |            |
--------------   --------------   --------------   --------------   --------------
```

**Tablet**

```
--------------   --------------   
|            |   |            |   
|            |   |            |   
|     1      |   |      2     |   
|            |   |            |   
|            |   |            |   
--------------   --------------  

--------------   --------------   
|            |   |            |   
|            |   |            |   
|     3      |   |      4     |   
|            |   |            |   
|            |   |            |  
--------------   --------------  

--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     5      |   
|            |    
|            |    
--------------
```

**Mobile**

```
--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     1      |   
|            |    
|            |    
-------------- 

--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     2      |   
|            |    
|            |    
-------------- 

--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     3      |   
|            |    
|            |    
-------------- 

--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     4      |   
|            |    
|            |    
-------------- 

--------------      
|            |   
|            |     
|     5      |   
|            |    
|            |    
--------------
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a codepen or set a code snippet, so it is easy to help you

Comment: Plz provide code snippet....

Comment: we can use `col-s-n-offset` for this no ?

Comment: Why don't you customize your bootstrap ? The default 12 cols are not what you need.... http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a five column layout easily, I created a small css file which makes you able to create 5, 8, and 10 equal sized column layout. [HERE](https://github.com/naeemshaikh27/Bootstrap-5-8-10)

```
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Now when you want the layout for 5in a row for lg, 2 in a row for md-sm, and 1 in a row for xs, you can create a layout like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6 "></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Now this is pretty good, but the problem you are facing is when you add `15px` margin between them.

---

To deal with this, you can insert divs inside your columns and treat them as realcolumns and add margin to them

```css
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-xs-15 {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
.realColumn {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6 ">
    <div class='realColumn'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6">
    <div class='realColumn'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6">
    <div class='realColumn'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6">
    <div class='realColumn'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6">
    <div class='realColumn'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6 "><div class='realColumn'></div></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"><div class='realColumn'></div></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"><div class='realColumn'></div></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"><div class='realColumn'></div></div>
     <div class="col-lg-15 col-sm-6"><div class='realColumn'></div></div>
</div>
```

see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XmjkG3msh4pi5DN4N6Nq?p=preview
shows exactly how to acheive this layout.

Comment: It's comes with ``30px`` margin because you used just ``margin`` instead of ``margin-right`` or ``margin-left``. Let me try to fix it. At the same time please try to help me if you have time.

Comment: One other issue is if I am using margin-left I have to exclude the left one and if using margin-right I have to exclude the last one. Same thing should be taken care in tablet and mobile screen also.

Comment: @devo.. you need to give margins using mediaQueries for that